# Displaying more images of size greater than 800*1024 for different activities background

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-image, bitmapimage

I have 20 to 25 Activities in application and each activity extends one common base activity. Each activity has one background image that contains of size some what large like 800*1024. This background image has been set in base activity.

For displaying these images I calculated scaling based on device width and height. I set this scale to `inSampleSize` of `BitmapFactory.Options`, then I recreated the bitmap.

I recycled bitmaps in `onDestroy` method of each activity and base activity.

Even though I am re-sizing images and recycling bitmaps, I am getting `OutOfMemoryError` after running some time.

Can anyone please guide me how to avoid this `OutOfMemoryError`?

Answer (score 0):

Here, in `lifecycle` of activity, you can see that activity will be visible to the user after `Resume` called. So you can write your code to create and set bitmap in `onResume()` method. As well when your activity goes in `background`, `onStop()` will called. So it is advisable to release your memory at this stage.

In your approach, when activity is `destroyed`, you are freeing memory. But instead of doing this, when activity is visible to user, `allocate` memory and `free` after activity hidden.

**Edit:**

You can also release bitmap in `onPause()`, but when you do this, you will see that first background will get **Black** then activity will be changed.

[image: Activity Lifecycle]

Answer (score 0):

check your code when you set "BitmapFactory.options" . usually it takes some time to create the UI. so if you set the BitmapFactory.options before creating the UI, you will get 0 from getWidth()/getHeight() methods. setting 0 to sample size does nothing. you have to set BitmapFactory.options after creating the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use AQuery(Android Query) for this purpose. This Api is easy to use and it automatically handle memory errors. It empower you app with lots of options.

You can download this from here :

[AndroidQuery.jar](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.24.3.jar)

You can get description from here :

[Android Query Complete Detail](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/)

For Image specific options you can visit :

[Android Query Image Doc](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading)